# Change related set name in Django

Tags: django, set, rename, django-queryset

I was wondering how to customize the name of a set in Django models.

In the tutorial exemple, Choice refers to Polls in a ForeignKey field. Later on, we can know what choices are available for a Poll with :

```
poll.choice_set.all
```

Is it possible to rename that set to something else, so I can query it with something like ? :

```
poll.my_choices.all
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Use the related_name argument in your ForeignKey.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Brilliant! I'm ashamed, I thought it was working the other way round. Thanks